# Input button onClick remove closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Erm, why this don`t work, iv used similar code like this for my site many times..butnow dont work..

HTML

```
<div><span>a</span><input type='hidden' /> <input type='button' onClick='Remove(event)' />
```

JQuery

```
function Remove(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('div').remove();
}
```

Looks like $(this) is not my button. I tested with alert($(this).val()) and nothing heppend.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you bind the event handler with jQuery since you're already using it? That would make things much easier.

Comment: My divs are created from clientside and serverside too. Its much easy to add onclick function instead to unbind-rebind all on new item, no?

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato you can use delegated events if you are worried about it being created dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about adding a class to the button element and bind a handler to the button

```
<div>
   <span>a</span>
   <input type='hidden' /> 
   <input type='button' class'removeDiv' />
```

**Code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.removeDiv').click (function () { 
         $(this).parent().remove();
         // As I see the input is direct child of the div
    });
});
```

> My divs are created from clientside and serverside too. Its much easy to add onclick function instead to unbind-rebind all on new item, no?

In such cases you can use delegated events. See below,

```
$(function () {
    //Replace document with any closest container that is available on load.
    $(document).on('click', '.removeDiv', function () { 
         $(this).parent().remove();
         // As I see the input is direct child of the div
    });
});
```

Comment: Your edit code works well for me. I didn`t know what i can assign click functions like this :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work!

HTML

```
<div><span>a</span><input type='hidden' /> <input type='button' onClick='Remove(this)' />
```

JQuery

```
function Remove(obj){
    $(obj).closest('div').remove();
}
```